# HTML 5 move Text like Margin but without Margin

Tags: html, css

How can I move text in HTML 5 like margin but without using margin because
two texts on my page repel each other with margin

Comment: What. Expand on your question please.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add padding, like indubitablee said.

Or you can create another div and wrap it around what you want, then add a margin to that.

Answer (score 0):

try using `padding` http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

padding is generally creating space within an element whereas margin is creating space outside of an element.  hope this helps